# Base64 decoded into ZIP - Mule

Tags: dataweave

I’m using an online base64 decoder (see below)  to decode the base64 string and create a zip file from it. How can I replicate this in DW 2.0? 
 https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_decode_file.html

Currently, I’m doing the following but when I save it into a file

```
%dw 2.0

import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/json

---
fromBase64(payload.body.checkRetrieveStatusResponse.result.zipFile)
```

I get string representation instead of a folder structure (the original base64 it’s actually a list of files)

Comment: What you say is that `result.zipFile` contains a base64 representation of a zip? If so then you should not write it as `application/json` but `application/octet-stream`
Can you please provide an example of the payload so the solution can be validated.

Answer (score 2):

Use binary data format instead of json

```
%dw 2.0

import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/octet-stream

---
fromBase64(payload.body.checkRetrieveStatusResponse.result.zipFile)
```